# images do not show up in backend

Tags: magento-1.7, import, image, backend, avs-fastsimpleimport

I am bugging on this problem for couple of days already. First the pictures were not even moved to `catalog/product/X/Y/XYimage.jpg`. I solved this and the images are copied and placed in the correct corresponding directory, but now they are not shown up in the admin panel. The product is imported successfully, and when I open it and check its images - there is none.

The function looks like that:

```
protected function _getImages($product)
    {
        $imageList = array();
        $importImagesDirectory = Mage::getBaseDir().DS.Mage::getStoreConfig('xmlimport/product/import_images_dir');
        $images = $product->xpath('//ns:Darstellung/ns:Info[@Art="Bild"]/@Wert');
        $imgCounter = 0;
        foreach($images as $oneImage)
        {
            $addImage = $this->_getDefaultEmptySettings();
            $addImage['_media_image'] = $importImagesDirectory . (string)$oneImage['Wert'];
            $addImage['_media_attribute_id'] = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getResource()->getAttribute('media_gallery')->getAttributeId();
            $addImage['_media_is_disabled'] = 0;
            $addImage['_media_position'] = $imgCounter;
            $addImage['_media_lable'] = (string)$oneImage['Wert'];
            $addImage['image'] = (string)$oneImage['Wert'];
            $addImage['small_image'] = (string)$oneImage['Wert'];
            $addImage['thumbnail'] = (string)$oneImage['Wert'];
            $imgCounter += 1;
            $imageList[] = $addImage;
        }
        return $imageList;
    }
```

then I am calling this function, and I assign the `$imageList` array to the array, that builds the complete product and imports it.
A single image in the `$imageList` array looks like that:

```
Array
(
    [sku] => 
    [_type] => 
    [_attribute_set] => 
    [_media_image] => C:\htdocs\my_repository\media/import/bildname_2.jpg
    [_media_attribute_id] => 88
    [_media_is_disabled] => 0
    [_media_position] => 1
    [_media_lable] => bildname_2.jpg
    [image] => bildname_2.jpg
    [small_image] => bildname_2.jpg
    [thumbnail] => bildname_2.jpg
)
```

So it is correct. When I debug and I come to the function `_saveProducts()` in `app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php` and to the exact following code:

```
           if (!empty($rowData['_media_image'])) {
                        $mediaGallery[$rowSku][] = array(
                            'attribute_id'      => $rowData['_media_attribute_id'],
                            'label'             => $rowData['_media_lable'],
                            'position'          => $rowData['_media_position'],
                            'disabled'          => $rowData['_media_is_disabled'],
                            'value'             => $rowData['_media_image']
                          );
                    }
//CLUE -> _media_image IS ALWAYS NULL
```

So I believe, that everything is going smooth until the images are copied and placed in the `catalog/product` folder, BUT THEY ARE NOT SET in the back-end. But this is going deep and I don't know where to search anymore...

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: When you view the catalog images for a product in the backend, is the default image set to none?

Comment: @GeoffJackson - I am sorry, I am not sure I understood you correctly. But there is no image shown at all, for the certain product.

Comment: Try setting the value for `_media_image` as a relative path to `media/import`, not with an absolute path. So in your case `bildname_2.jpg` instead of `C:\htdocs\my_repository\media/import/bildname_2.jpg`

Comment: @Marius - oh, man, I will come all the way to Romania and give you a case of beer! I just want to ask - can you elaborate with a few words, why it would work with a relative path, but wouldn't work with an absolute?

Comment: It's because of this: `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product::_getUploader()`. See the values for `$tmpDir` and `$destDir`....Can you make it Delirium Tremens :) http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Delirium_Tremens.jpg ?

Answer (score 3):

Just so this question would have an answer:
Based on the comments, the problem is that the values for the images have to be the relative path to the images in `media/import`. The import does not work with absolute path images, because of `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product::_getUploader()`

```
$tmpDir     = Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir() . '/import';
```

and the value of `Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir()` is `media`.
So in the end the value for `$tmpDir` is `media/import`

Comment: Its not working,

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/t1o6Elw.png